# Use user id or user pk as value in Django Models ForeignKey

Tags: django-models, userid

I'm trying to assign the value of the user id or user pk to ForeignKey attrs. all I got is:

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=int('pk'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pk'

Here is my code:

class View(models.Model):

```
Data = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Den = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Obs = models.CharField(max_length=200)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='pk')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.Data}-{self.Den}-{self.Value}-{self.Obs}'
```

P.S. if i assing a static value to 'default', the model working without problems.

Does anyone know how I can solve it? Thank you in advance

Comment: You can not do this, a model is request-unaware, so there is no logged in user at the model layer. You simply pass it in a view.

Comment: Thank you Willem, for your answer.

Is this not possible when adding data to Forms? a column to hold user_id, to be added automatically, as a normal field when inserting new data.

Comment: if you alter the form yes. Some Django forms do that iirc.

Comment: Thank you again Willem, i'ved tried to solve it from forms, but without success. All what i get was a Select with usernames. When i select one in db is write the user_id. Can you, please, help me to write the form corectly? I want to complete the form and when i select save to autocomplete de database with user_id. Thank you  very much

Comment: This is the form code:     class ViewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = View
        fields = {'Data', 'Den', 'Value', 'Obs'}

        widgets = {
            'Data': widgets.SelectDateWidget(years=YEARS),
            'Den': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Den', 'class': 'form_control'}),
            'Value': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Value', 'class': 'form_control'}),
            'Obs': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Obs', 'class': 'form_control'}),
        }